# Geometrical interpretation $\frac{1}{6}\pi \le arg\frac{z(1+i)}{-1+i} \le \frac{1}{3}\pi$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'd like to ask you about the example below (I have to draw a geometrical interpretation in an argand diagram). Am I doing the right thing?

$$\frac{\pi}{6}\le \arg\frac{z(1+i)}{-1+i} \le \frac{\pi}{3}.$$

First step:

$$\frac{\pi}{6} \le \arg(-iz) \le \frac{\pi}{3}.$$

Then

$$\arg(-iz) = \arg(-i) + \arg(z) = \arg(z) - \frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi,$$
where $k$ is an integer
For $k = 0$:

$$\frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{\pi}{2} \le \arg(z) \le \frac{\pi}{3} +\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\frac{2\pi}{3} \le \arg(z) \le \frac{5\pi}{6}.$$

Is my geometrical interpretation correct? Should I exclude the $(0,0)$ point?

[image: Geometric interpretation]